# Template tags in django

Tags: python, django

In djangobook in chapter 9 on advanced templates it shows how the `{% comment %}` tag is implemented.

```
def do_comment(parser, token):
    nodelist = parser.parse(('endcomment',))
    parser.delete_first_token()
    return CommentNode()

class CommentNode(template.Node):
    def render(self, context):
        return ''
```

According to the book in the function `do_comment` after parser.parse() is called, the parser hasn’t yet “consumed” the `{% endcomment %}` tag, so the code needs to explicitly call parser.delete_first_token() to prevent that tag from being processed twice. Can anyone please explain what does that mean.

Comment: don't read djangobook, it's out of date. go to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/

Comment: Why don't you just remove that line and see what happens?

Answer (score 2):

The django [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#parsing-until-another-block-tag) says:

> After parser.parse() is called, the parser hasn’t yet “consumed” the
>   {% endcomment %} tag, so the code needs to explicitly call
>   parser.delete_first_token().

The official doc(which is used by the django book) explains why `parser.delete_first_token()` should be called. But it does not explain `why  he parser hasn’t yet “consumed” the {% endcomment %}`. I guess that's what confuses you.

Let's take the `block` tag for example.

Because we can optionally give the `endblock` tag node a name, we need to check whether the name matchws the one defined in the `block` tag node.

So for most cases we can simply ignore the `endxxx` tag node, but in some cases, we need to get the last tag node and do extra stuff.

```
@register.tag('block')
def do_block(parser, token):
    ...
    nodelist = parser.parse(('endblock',))

    # This check is kept for backwards-compatibility. See #3100.
    endblock = parser.next_token()
    acceptable_endblocks = ('endblock', 'endblock %s' % block_name)
    if endblock.contents not in acceptable_endblocks:
        parser.invalid_block_tag(endblock, 'endblock', acceptable_endblocks)

    return BlockNode(block_name, nodelist)
```